# Unable to open multiple images through openCV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am learning image processing for my project, I want to open multiple images from a folder, but the problem is the image files are loaded but when I tried to display it through matplot lib only one image is shown.Code is

```
      img_dir=r"D:\UCP\Machine Learning A-Z\facialExp\images"
      valid_image_extensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".tif", ".tiff"] 
      #specify your vald extensions here
      valid_image_extensions = [item.lower() for item in 
      valid_image_extensions]
      image_path_list=[]

      for file in os.listdir(img_dir):
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        if extension.lower() not in valid_image_extensions:
         continue
        image_path_list.append(os.path.join(img_dir, file))



      for image_file in image_path_list:
         image=cv2.imread(image_file)

        if image is not None:
          plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
        elif image is None:
          print ("Error loading: " + image_file)
          #end this loop iteration and move on to next image
          continue
```

In first loop the dirrectories of all images are saved in image_path_list, but when I want to plot in second loop only one is plotted.
kindly suggest I am missing or doing something wrong..

Comment: Is this all nested in a for loop? I ask because of the continue at the bottom. also it looks like you can iterating over the 'image' variable instead of making a list or simply plotting in the for loop. Did you mean to have the last 5 lines indented to the for loop?

Comment: the statement after for loop are the part of for loop,

Comment: `if image is not None: .... elif image is None: ...` -- There's a third option? If not, then the second test is redundant.

Comment: Yes I know i just added it while checking the problem, I have removed the second part still only image is plotting...

Comment: I believe it is actually showing 2 images, however the 1 is overlaying the other because you are on the same plot. try making a figure for each plot `fig = plt.figure()' before the plt.imshow()

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the `image` variable multiple times, because you are in a `for` loop. So you are basically loading an image on top of the other, and only the last image will show.

For your code to work you will need to plot everytime you load the image.

Your code probably is just wrongly indented, if you indent one tab the if statement for the plotting, it should work